# plpgsql cte parameterizing with array cause error message

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I'll try to inject and array of ids to a complex select query

```
CREATE FUNCTION permission_cache_update(
  IN affected_user_list INT4[]
)
  RETURNS TABLE(user_id INT4, permission_id INT4)
AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH
    affected_user AS (
      SELECT unnest(affected_user_list) AS user_id
    ), 
    permission_summary AS
    (
      SELECT affected_user.user_id, role_permission.permission_id
      FROM user_role, role_permission, affected_user
      WHERE role_permission.role_id = user_role.role_id AND user_role.user_id = affected_user.user_id
      UNION
      SELECT affected_user.user_id, user_permission.permission_id
      FROM user_permission, affected_user
      WHERE user_permission.user_id = affected_user.user_id
    )
    SELECT user_id, permission_id
    FROM permission_summary
    GROUP BY user_id, permission_id;
  END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

The problem is with this part:

```
    affected_user AS (
      SELECT unnest(affected_user_list) AS user_id
    ),
```

But I don't know how to fix it. The error message is meaningless.

> ```
> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
> ```

I want to use the `user_id, permission_id` pairs to update the permission cache which contains the same values. So it will be faster to ask the user permissions because they will be cached in there. I want to use the db for storing and checking session permissions. I don't know whether it is a wise thing or not ...

Comment: I tagged Postgres 8.4, which is an *educated guess*. Please amend if that's not the case. Next time please remember to provide your version right away.

Comment: It's 8.4, sorry I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I derive from your previous question that you are using PostgreSQL **8.4**, which is pretty outdated by now.
*You need to provide this information with every question!*

In your function header you declare

```
RETURNS TABLE(user_id INT4, permission_id INT4)
```

The `OUT` parameters `user_id` and `permission_id` are *visible everywhere* in the function body in PL/pgSQL. To avoid naming conflicts you need to table-qualify columns of the same name. Your function would not work properly with modern Postgres either, since the reference in your final `SELECT` would return `NULL` values:

```
SELECT user_id, permission_id
```

Postgres 8.4 had more problems with that and errors out at

```
SELECT unnest(affected_user_list) AS user_id
```

The **naming conflict** is unacceptable to the old version. Newer versions have resolved this.

#### sql function

You can use this **SQL function** with a **largely simplified** query instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION permission_cache_update(affected_user_list int[])
  RETURNS TABLE(user_id int, permission_id int) AS
$func$

WITH affected_user AS (SELECT unnest($1) AS user_id) 
SELECT a.user_id, r.permission_id
FROM   user_role       u
JOIN   role_permission r USING (role_id)
JOIN   affected_user   a USING (user_id)

UNION
SELECT a.user_id, p.permission_id
FROM   user_permission p
JOIN   affected_user   a USING (user_id)

$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

- Use proper join syntax. Much easier to read and maintain.
  I also simplified with `USING`, which is a matter of taste and style. It's simpler and shorter, but requires unambiguous column names. So that would not work in a plpgsql version for Postgres 8.4 either, but works in modern versions.
- The final `SELECT` with the `GROUP BY` in your original query is just noise.
  `UNION` (as opposed to `UNION ALL`) already implicitly removes duplicates.

#### plpgsql function

If you avoid the naming conflicts, the plpgsql version should also work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION permission_cache_update(affected_user_list int[])
  RETURNS TABLE(user_id int, permission_id int) AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
WITH affected_user AS (
   SELECT unnest(affected_user_list) AS u_id
   ) 
SELECT a.user_id, r.permission_id
FROM   user_role       u
JOIN   role_permission r USING (role_id)
JOIN   affected_user   a ON a.u_id = u.user_id

UNION
SELECT a.user_id, p.permission_id
FROM   user_permission p
JOIN   affected_user   a ON a.u_id = p.user_id;

END    
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Nice catch on the naming conflicts!

Comment: Yepp, the problem was the name duplication, it does not work with the same name...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the problem is with the section you cited? I just created a reduced version of the function and it works.  What version of Postgres are you trying this on? Maybe some functionality doesn't work in your version (I tested on 9.2).

What I tested:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS permission_cache_update(int4[]);
CREATE FUNCTION permission_cache_update(
  IN affected_user_list INT4[]
)
  RETURNS TABLE(user_id INT4, user_id2 INT4)
AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH
    affected_user AS (
      SELECT unnest(affected_user_list) AS user_id
    ),
    foo as (select * from affected_user)
    select au.*, foo.*
    from affected_user au
    inner join foo using (user_id);
  END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

select * from permission_cache_update(array[1,2,3]::int4[]);

 user_id | user_id2 
---------+----------
       1 |        1
       2 |        2
       3 |        3
```

Comment: I think your guess is right. The error can be reproduced in Postgres 8.4.

Comment: Yepp, the version is 8.4